# How to determine Key that through Input/ActionMap binding caused AbstractAction to be fired?

Tags: java, key-bindings, keyevent

I'm building an InputMap and ActionMap to bind keys to methods. Many of the keys will do similar things. I have one entry in the InputMap for each bound key. I would like to associate several InputMap entries with the same ActionMap entry, and use the ActionEvent parameter in the AbstractAction.actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) method to determine which key was pressed/relesed/typed. I've looked at getID(), tested to see if the ActionEvent was a KeyEvent (it is not). Is there a way to do this, or must I have refactor differently so that each unique ActionMap entry sets a parameter and then calls my (paramaterized) method?

Here is what works (but is verbose):

```
    getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT,0),"myRightHandler");
    getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT,0),"myLeftHandler");
    getActionMap().put("myRightHandler",new AbstractAction() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                  System.out.println("Typed Right Arrow");
              }
          });
    getActionMap().put("myLefttHandler",new AbstractAction() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                  System.out.println("Typed Left Arrow");
              }
          });
```

Here is what I would like to do but can't find the magic:

```
    getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT,0),"myGenericHandler");
    getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT,0),"myGenericHandler");
    getActionMap().put("myGenericHandler",new AbstractAction() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                  // determine what key caused the event...
                  // evt.getKeyCode() does not work.
                  int keyCode = performMagic(evt);
                  switch (keyCode) {
                      case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                          System.out.println("Typed Right Arrow");
                          break;
                      case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                          System.out.println("Typed Left Arrow");
                          break;
                      default:
                          System.out.println("Typed unknown key");
                          break;
                  }
              }
          };
```

Comment: That kind of violates the point of the input/action mappings. While only key strokes are currently implemented, the API has been designed for other input types.  The point is, the `Action` shouldn't care how it was activated

Comment: @MadProgrammer So should I be using a KeyListener instead?

Comment: No, the input/action mappings API was designed to make it easier then having to resort to using `KeyListener`.  Design a better `Action` hierarchy.  If, for example, you have a need to provide movement actions, design a basic class that knows what it's changing and how it's changing it (ie change the x position by -1).  For each movement key, assign it the required action, established to your requirements.

Comment: @MadProgrammer OK, that's the refactoring I had in mind when I mentioned it in the OP. While I would be able to factor out much of the underlying implementation, it would still require a "connector" Action for each InputMap entry which would then call the common factored implementation with the needed parameters. Is that correct?

Comment: If that's what your model needs to do, then yes...

Answer (score 0):

You should try this simple logic first.

```
getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT,0),"myRightHandler");
    getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT,0),"myLeftHandler");
    getActionMap().put("myRightHandler", new myAction("myRightHandler")); 
    getActionMap().put("myLeftHandler", new myAction("myLeftHandler")); 

    class myAction extends AbstractAction { 

        String str; 

        public myAction(String actName) {

            str = actName; 
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { 

            switch(str) { 

                case "myRightHandler": //Here is code for 'myRightHandler'. 
                break; 

                case "myLeftHandler": //Here is code for 'myLeftHandler'. 
                break; 
                .
                .
                .
                .
                default : //Here is default Action; 
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now this way you may add many-many custom key-combinations and action and differ them with switch.

Comment: @mentallurg Is format of code is so important? You just have to understand the logic I have given to you.

Comment: It is still not formatted. It means you force others to spend their valuable time trying to understand you unformatted code. It means you **don't respect** the community.